# Dynamic real-time graph calculation

Tags: c#, graph, timer, ticker

I have a dynamic graph that plots every second with a timer on the X-axis ticking up and a calculation called battery discharge on the Y-axis. The battery discharge is a formula that uses the timer to calculate it so that over time the battery will eventually discharge to 0. **The problem is that on the graph, it only shows and calculates the initial charge of the battery. How do I make it so that it dynamically calculates the charge every second.**
Below is the code for the calculation of the battery discharge using the getter and setter.

```
 public double dTime { get { return time; } set { time = value; batteryDischargeCalc(); } }
        private double time;

    private void batteryDischargeCalc()
    {

        bEnergy = (nVoltage * capacity * 3600)/1000000; //battery energy in megajoules
        energyDischarge = bEnergy - ((motorPower/1000) * time ); //discharge after certain amount of time in megajoules
    }
```

Below is the code that initiates the graph drawing.

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            graphStart = true;
            globalTimer.timer.Start();
            graphForm.Show();
            battery.Capacity = Convert.ToDouble(textBox3.Text);
            battery.Nvoltage = Convert.ToDouble(textBox4.Text);
            battery.MotorPower = Convert.ToDouble(textBox5.Text);
            battery.dTime = Convert.ToDouble(tCount);
```

Below is the code for the graph plotting. In the ticker.

```
   private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (graphStart == true)
        {
            graphForm.TimeGraph(tCount);
            graphForm.chartGraph["Energy Discharge"].Points.AddXY(tCount, battery.energyDischarge);

        }
        else
        {
            tCount++;
            resform.GiveTime(tCount);
        }  
    }
```

Comment: Your calculation is based on a time variable that doesn't get changed anywhere in the code you've posted. Did you forget to update the dTime property in Timer_Tick?

Comment: @RogerN oh i didn't realise I had to do it in Timer_Tick Thank you.